# C# prevent overwriting text field

Tags: c#, encryption, overwrite

I have this code in C#, but the code for shifting inside a block overwrites the code for shifting `d` letters. How can I solve this so that they don't overwrite each other anymore?
This is the code:

```
private void Crypt(int n, int m, int d)
{
    // make a block from the string
    string invoerstring = invoer.Text;
    uitvoer.Text = invoerstring;

    // shift d letters
    char[] buffer = invoerstring.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        // Letter.
        char letter = buffer[i];
        // Add shift to all.
        letter = (char)(letter + d);
        // Subtract 26 on overflow.
        // Add 26 on underflow.
        if (letter > 'z')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter - 26);
        }   
        else if (letter < 'a')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter + 26);
        }
        // Store.
        buffer[i] = letter;
    }
    uitvoer.Text+=buffer;

    //shift characters inside a block
    var shift = String.Concat(invoerstring.Skip(m).Concat(invoerstring.Take(m)));
    uitvoer.Text = shift;  
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Crypt(8,2,1);
}
```

Comment: You are assigning values to `uitvoer.Text` twice. So the last value sticks. What outcome are you looking for?

Comment: I know im assigning values to uitvoer.Text twice. I want both values to be sticked, then I got the outcome I'm looking for. How do I do that?

Comment: @Sybren: Hi, I was wondering how you are progressing :)

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

- Your code is modifying the control `Uitvoer`. Try to force to prevent this. Seperate UI-code (which modifies UI-components) from logic (to encrypt something). It think with this hint alone your should succeed, because now you are trying to write back your result to early.
- You said it yourself: the second operation overwrites the result of the first. The line where you shift a block uses `invoerstring` but `invoerstring` was not modifed in any way by the code that shifts the letters. You should use the result of the last operation: `buffer`.
- Am I correct that parameter `n` is never used?

Try this:

```
private string Crypt(string input, int m, int d)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach(char ch in input)
    {
        // Add shift to all.
        char letter = (char)(ch + d);
        // Subtract 26 on overflow.
        // Add 26 on underflow.
        if (letter > 'z')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter - 26);
        }   
        else if (letter < 'a')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter + 26);
        }
        // Store.
        result += letter;
    }

    //shift characters inside a block
    result = result.Substring(m) + result.Substring(0, m);
    return result;  
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uitvoer.Text = Crypt(invoer.Text, 2, 1);
}
```

If you want both the block-shift and the charachter shift displayed: add a `+` to the last line:

```
result += result.Substring(m) + result.Substring(0, m);
```

Comment: Tried this, I think foreach(chat letter in input) has to be foreach(char letter in input). When I change this I get an 3 times the same error : Cannot assign to 'letter' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: @Sybren: You are correct. I typed my answer in a hurry. I adjusted my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are using `uitvoer.Text+=buffer;` which I think is the problem. The type of the char array is being assigned as text 'System.Char[]' here.

The below modified code replaces each character by the next dth character (so 'a' is replaced by 'b') and then rotates the charaters towards left by m characters.

e.g. a input of 'abcde' gives the o/p 'defbc' with m = 2 and d = 1 
[abcde -> bcdef (replace by the next character) ->  defbc (move left by 2) ]

```
private static void Crypt(int n, int m, int d)
{
    // make a block from the string
    string invoerstring = invoer.Text;
    string uitv = "";

    // shift d letters
    char[] buffer = invoerstring.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        // Letter.
        char letter = buffer[i];
        // Add shift to all.
        letter = (char)(letter + d);
        // Subtract 26 on overflow.
        // Add 26 on underflow.
        if (letter > 'z')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter - 26);
        }
        else if (letter < 'a')
        {
            letter = (char)(letter + 26);
        }
        // Store.
        buffer[i] = letter;
        uitv += letter;
    }

    //shift characters inside a block
    var shift = String.Concat(uitv.Skip(m).Concat(uitv.Take(m)));
    uitv = shift;
    uitvoer.Text = uitv;
}
```

Comment: -1 so far - while it may be a working code for poster's question it is not good format for SO. Posting wall of code and answer without any explanation or comments does not provide good value for OP and future readers.

Comment: Tried the code above but it has the same result as my own code. The characters are shifted inside a block, but the letters aren't shifted. An a for example has to become an b when d = 1.

Comment: @Sybren - Edited my answer. please check now if this is what was needed. Alexei - I agree. I should have added more text.